# Wordpress redirects to a similar link

Tags: wordpress

I have this page in Wordpress:

http://www.bookup.com/chess-openings-wizard-android/setting-up-dropbox/

In Wordpress if I click on the link (next to word "Permalink") Wordpress instead brings up this similar page:

http://www.bookup.com/chess-openings-wizard-ipad/setting-up-dropbox/

If I paste that first link into an incognito window, it goes to the correct page.

What can I do to stop the redirection to the similar page?

Comment: Try resaving your permalinks under settings. That should solve any permalink issues.

Comment: @GavinSimpson Yep, I didn't change any of the settings but clicking Save Changes cleared up the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Gavin Simpson's comment, clicking Save Changes in the Permalinks settings fixed the problem even though no changes were made to the settings.